# How do jmps work in assembly? (OS development)

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system

I'm just starting to teach myself assembly to learn how code and operating systems really work. As I understand this, `jmp foo` tells the processor to go to the line containing the label `foo`. However, the most basic OS (if it can really be called that!) looks like this...

```
foo:                           ; label foo
    jmp foo                    ; Go to foo
    times 512-($-$$) db 0      ; Fill remaining bytes with 0's
```

As I understand this code, the processor sees line 1 and remembers that it is `foo`. Then it continues to line 2, which tells it to go to `foo`. And repeat, never reaching line 3 telling it to fill in the empty space.

Why is this not an infinite loop? It runs quite well on VirtualBox when compiled (Am I using the right word here?) into an .iso file.

Comment: `jmp` is simply "go fetch instruction X bytes from here". It's kind of what you said but of course in addresses not lines. In terms of lines it would be "jump to X lines from here" and `jmp foo` would be "jump -1 lines from here", of course that's just an analogy

Comment: @MargaretBloom Right, but how is the third line ever executed?

Comment: It **is** an infinite loop, and the third line isn't an instruction, it's an assembler directive to fill the rest of the sector with zeroes. It's "executed" by the assembler during assembling.

Comment: That's not an instruction. It's an assembly directive to fill the rest of the output, up to the offset 512, with zeros. Do you mean `times 512- ...` right? BTW that line is not useful as it leaves no space for the boot signature.

Comment: Also `foo:` is a label, it's not seen or remembered by the processor - the assembler does that, and puts the appropriate relative address into the `jmp`. So your code is just 1 instruction at runtime.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that this isn't executed on startup, it is writing to the disk and what is written is executed, got it. Also, I thought that the boot sig. was optional and that was mostly outdated

Comment: Use a disassembler (like `objdump -drw`) to look at the bytes and how they decode.  That should make it a lot more clear what the CPU sees in memory when it's fetching machine code to decode and execute.

Comment: I don't know if people would like this approach, but I would recommend going through the programming model and the architecture of the Intel 8085 microprocessor in detail, if you want to get a starting point. Then you can extend that understanding and get into x86, and for each instruction you will find precise description in the Intel developer's manual.

Comment: On top of all the other comments. A boot sector is 512 bytes long. The last word (16-bit value) needs to be 0xAA55 for it to be detected as bootable media. You really should be using `times 510-($-$$) db 0` followed by `dw 0xAA55`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Margret mentioned that earlier as well, I swore I read somewhere that was out of date, but I guess not. I do have it in my code now, though! Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing; this is assembly code, so this is not what is going to executed by the processor directly. Assembler plays a role here. It scans your assembly code and create machine code. which is a sequence of [Instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) (Data too).

let's come to your code

```
foo:                           ; label foo
jmp foo                        ; Go to foo
times 512-($-$$) db 0          ; Fill remaining bytes with 0's
```

Assembler look at your program. And saves address of "foo" i.e. 0x00000000 (Zero)
First Instruction is jump at address of 0x00000000 (Labels has no size) which tells the processor to jump to foo i.e. jump to 0x00000000. So assembler creates a binary file, It puts "jmp" instruction machine code and put 0x00000000 in address field.

Next "times" this is not a machine executable code, It is rather a assembler keyword which tells the assembler to operate the followed command n time. so fill rest space with "0" bytes till the address 512.

So Output binary would look like this.

[image]

So Actually It is an **infinite loop**!